# Using Wolfram Language in Java

Tags: java, jvm, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I work on a statistical project written on Java. But I have a piece of legacy code written on Wolfram Language.

Is there any way to convert this code to Java code? Or how can I use Wolfram Language in my Java project?

Comment: As always documentation might be handy
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/guide/CallingTheWolframLanguageFromJava.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html

Comment: You can try the [Symja library](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library), which has a big subset of functions available. See [symja_android_library/doc/functions](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library/tree/master/symja_android_library/doc/functions)